# Redeclare Width property for a custom Delphi component

Tags: delphi, properties, components

I have a custom Delphi component descending from TGraphicControl. Its class is declared as follows :

```
TMyLabel = class(TGraphicControl)
private
  ...
protected
  ...
public
  ...
published
  property Height;
  property Width write SetWidth;
  ...
end;
```

The implementation of SetWidth lies further :

```
procedure TMyLabel.SetWidth(const Value: Integer);
begin
  if (Value >= 0) and (Value <> Width)
  then begin
    inherited Width := Value;
    // Do some other stuff
    ...
  end;
  MessageDlg('Test', mtInformation, [mbOK], 0);
end;
```

I currently get SetWidth called when the width of the component is changed programmatically at runtime or at design time by entering a value in the corresponding field of the object inspector. However, when I resize the component at design time using the mouse, the object inspector 'Width' field is updated but no message box shows up, so my SetWidth procedure is not called.

I need SetWidth to be called while mouse-resizing the component, so that I can set a flag for the Paint procedure to know when it must do some other stuff (besides just redrawing the component). Is there a way to achieve this ?

Comment: +1 because it brought 3 good and complementary answers. Of course it has merits on its own, if only for the mistakes to avoid ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While [Mason Wheeler's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251324/redeclare-width-property-for-a-custom-delphi-component/4251384#4251384) is the answer to your question, I would like to warn you.

Overriding properties can give strange results since you can't have 'virtual' properties and SetWidth is also not virtual. If someone is using a descendant of your class to set the Width property, your code would not be called. Therefore I advice against overriding properties in this way.

```
var Control: TControl;
begin
 Control := MyLabel;
 Control.Width := 5000; // TMyLabel.SetWidth is not called!!
```

Furthermore: setting the Width property is not the only way to change the width of a control as [Deltics explains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251324/redeclare-width-property-for-a-custom-delphi-component/4255166#4255166). You should override TControl.SetBounds.

```
var MyLabel: TMyLabel;
begin
 MyLabel.SetBounds(0, 0, 100, 100); // TMyLabel.SetWidth nor TControl.SetWidth is called!!
```

But it seems like you want to limit the width of your control. Then you better override **TControl.CanResize** which is made for that purpose. Or if you just want to react to a resize of any kind you better override **TControl.Resize**.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I should be able to solve my problem with TControl.Resize.

Comment: Hi Lars, the only and very reason for us, ordinary people, to post questions in this site, is exactly because we don't have the time nor the skills to dig into the vcl source to find whatever thing that will answer our questions. For that pourpose, we rely on the expertise of you, clever people, otherwise, this site would be usseless. Saying so, with thou respect, I found the last sentence of your answer, let's say, a bit arrogant and defintely unnecessary. Best regards.

Comment: @user2383818, you are right. I have removed the sentence

Answer (score 6):

I can't check right now, but iirc I suspect that the designer resizes your control using SetBounds() rather than setting individual left, top, width and height properties.

Fortunately, SetBounds() is virtual so you can simply override this in your custom control class.

Answer (score 4):

When you redeclare Width, you need to specify both the **read** and the **write** for it or you won't be able to modify it in the Object Inspector.  If you're not going to change the way reading works, then just give it a dummy function:

```
procedure TMyLabel.GetWidth: Integer;
begin
  result := inherited Width;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks, but it then seems strange that I could change the Width of the component in the object inspector without specifying a read accessor alongside the write one in the property declaration.